# Check for facebook thumbs up for botframework (node.js)

Tags: node.js, facebook, azure, facebook-like, botframework

I am facing an issue whereby unable to whether the user sent a "Thumbs Up".

I have found a package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-facebook-thumbs-up), however I am still unable to detect the "thumbs up".

**Desired**: When user press on the "thumbs up" of facebook, it should return "haha thanks!".

**Actual**: When user press on the "thumbs up" of facebook, it should return "Sorry, I'm not set up to answer that.".

Please advise on the issue

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which version of the BotBuilder SDK are you using? (v3 or v4)

Comment: @Mick, sorry, may i know how do i check for the version of my current botbuilder sdk?

Comment: @Mick, if i'm not wrong, i'm using BotBuilder SDK 3.

Comment: Please copy over your code rather than posting images of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [
function (session) {
    // Check whether the user pressed the Facebook Thumbs Up
    // button in Messenger, and respond appropriately:
    var msg = session.message.sourceEvent.message.sticker_id;
    if (msg == "369239263222822" || msg == "369239343222814" || msg == "369239383222810") {
        session.send('haha thanks!');
    }
    else {
        session.send('Sorry, I’m not set up to answer that.');
    }
}
```

]);

Comment: If this works for you, go ahead an mark it as correct